# Convergence of gPC expansions for random variables in the total variation distance

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-calculus, limits-and-convergence, orthogonal-polynomials

Suppose that a random variable $Y$ can be written as $Y=g(Z)$, where $g$ is a function and $Z$ is a random variable. When $Z$ is a continuous random variable with finite absolute moments, we consider a sequence of orthogonal polynomials with respect to the density function $f_Z$, $\{\phi_m(Z)\}_{m=0}^\infty$, which is called the generalized polynomial chaos (gPC) basis. Then $Y$ has the following gPC expansion:
$$ Y= \sum_{m=0}^\infty y_m \phi_m(Z), \quad y_m=\frac{E[f(Z)\phi_m(Z)]}{E[\phi_m(Z)^2]}. $$
These expansions can be generalized to random vectors $Z$ and have lots of applications when solving stochastic systems. An introduction is presented in the book [*Numerical Methods for Stochastic Computations, A Spectral Method Approach*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctv7h0skv), by Dongbin Xiu (2010).

As discussed in the book, convergence of gPC expansions holds in the mean square sense when the support of $Z$ is bounded. Moreover, this convergence is spectral (the smoother $g$ is, faster convergence holds; if $g$ is analytic, exponential convergence holds). In the paper [*On the convergence of generalized polynomial chaos expansions*](http://www.mathe.tu-freiberg.de/~ernst/PubArchive/genpc_m2an.pdf), ESAIM: M2AN 46 (2012) 317-339, it is proved that mean square convergence holds when the moment problem for $Z$ is uniquely solvable.

My question is whether there is any theoretical result in the literature that guarantees convergence of gPC expansions in the [total variation distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures).

Comment: Do you mean GPC (generalized polynomial chaos) expansions up to English grammar?

Comment: @user64494 It is always written as gPC (look up any reference on uncertainty quantification, for example the book I mentioned in the question). I do not know the exact reason. There are PC (polynomial chaos) expansions, which are the polynomial expansions arising from $Z$ Gaussian and $\{\phi_m(Z)\}_{m=0}^\infty$ Hermite polynomials. Then Xiu and Karniadakis generalized PC expansions to distributions of $Z$ that belong to the Wiener-Askey scheme. This gave rise to gPC (generalized polynomial chaos) expansions.